# Using the React HOC pattern, why is returning a Component same as returning a function the returns a JSX Component?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I've got a React HOC defined as follows and it works as I would expect.

```
function higherOrderComponent(Component) {
  return Component;
}
```

My question, is what JavaScript principle makes returning a function that returns a JSX equivalent?

```
function higherOrderComponent(Component) {
  return function () {
    return <Component></Component>;
  };
}
```

Is this related somehow to Identity in functional programming?

Comment: Are you familiar with Function Components? Because the second example is making one of those and then returning it. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: They are not the same, the second one ignores the props. The first is an id function (returning what is passed in: `id=>id`). The second one returns a functional component that ignores props and renders Component without props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't involve any complex principles or magic. In the first example you are returning a component object itself without rendering it. In the second example, you are returning a function component which returns a rendered version of the original component (this is much more common when writing HOCs since it allows you to make more modifications, such as wrapping the component in a div). The end result of both is the same as long as the component takes no arguments. If it did take arguments you would probably want your second example to be this:

```
function higherOrderComponent(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}
```